# how to set a async: false in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html

please help me how i can put an async: false in this code

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.100:8080/m-help/apps/json_doctor.php", function(data) {
    $.each(data.result, function(){ 
        $("#list").append("<li><a href='doctor-details.html?id=" +this['id']+ "'><span class='img'>      <img src='http://192.168.1.100:8080/m-help/images/upload/"+this['images']+"' alt=''/></span>" +this['doclname']+ ", " +this['docFname']+ "</a></li>");
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you need that? what is the context?

Comment: You should avoid synchronous AJAX calls. Its called AJAX for a reason!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The jQuery shorthand ajax functions have very limited customisation available to them. Use `.ajax` instead.

```
function success (data) {
    $.each(data.result, function(){ 
        $("#list").append("<li><a href='doctor-details.html?id=" +this['id']+ "'><span class='img'>      <img src='http://192.168.1.100:8080/m-help/images/upload/"+this['images']+"' alt=''/></span>" +this['doclname']+ ", " +this['docFname']+ "</a></li>");
    });
});

var url = "http://192.168.1.100:8080/m-help/apps/json_doctor.php";

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  success: success,
  async: false // This is horrible and will lock up the UI while it runs
});
```